# Create a instance of KeyPairGeneratorSpec

Tags: android, android-keystore, key-pair

I need to create an instance of android [KeyPairGeneratorSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.html), it used to be possible by using this [builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.html) class, but it is deprecated in API 23. Then, what is the right way to create it now???

In general, I need to create a [KeyPairGeneratorSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.html) with a key size. How to do it now?

Answer (score 0):

`KeyPairGeneratorSpec` has been deprecated in favour of [KeyGenParameterSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html).

I wouldn't necessarily move over to using `KeyGenParameterSpec` just because `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` is deprecated, because you'd have to write separate code paths for the two if you wanted to avoid using deprecated classes and maintain back-compatibility at the same time.

Here's some example code using the new `KeyGenParameterSpec` (from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.security.keystore.KeyGenParameterSpec)):

```
/**
 * Creates a symmetric key in the Android Key Store which can only be used after the user has
 * authenticated with fingerprint.
 */
public void createKey() {
    // The enrolling flow for fingerprint. This is where you ask the user to set up fingerprint
    // for your flow. Use of keys is necessary if you need to know if the set of
    // enrolled fingerprints has changed.
    try {
        // Set the alias of the entry in Android KeyStore where the key will appear
        // and the constrains (purposes) in the constructor of the Builder
        mKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        mKeyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                        // of the key
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        mKeyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I will give a try tomorrow then accept your answer :)

Comment: I don't understand why you say "I wouldn't necessarily move over to using KeyGenParameterSpec just because KeyPairGeneratorSpec is deprecated", if it is deprecated, isn't it so that you anyhow need to have another code path for the newer OS (api 23+), because the `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` is deprected, which means it is not available in Android 6.0+?

Comment: @Leem.fin, no, `deprecated` does not mean it's not available - only that [you're recommended not to use it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) because they want you to use another (better) method. They may well remove it in a future version, but `deprecated` is just a hint to try and guide developers to stop using it. If following best practices then *you should* try to stop using `deprecated` classes because otherwise you may update your target sdk in the future and find it's no longer supported.